# How to make verify If-Match header for /{repository}/{id}/{property} Spring-data-rest?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am using spring-data-rest and do request like PUT `/{repository}/{id}/{property}`

```
Body:
/12
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: text/uri-list
If-Match: 42 (incorrect value)
```

I expect to get 412 error but returned 204.

When I debugged I found out that DispatcherServlet use `HandlerExecutionChain with [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController#createPropertyReference(RootResourceInformation, HttpMethod, CollectionModel, Serializable, String)] and 3 interceptors` and that method does not check if-Match value.

And only requests like: PUT, PATCH, DELETE `/{repository}/{id}` use `HandlerExecutionChain with [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController#patchItemResource(RootResourceInformation, PersistentEntityResource, Serializable, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler, ETag, String)] and 3 interceptors` that check if-Match value.

Is it possible to make spring-data-rest verify if-Match value for PUT, DELETE, PATCH `/{repository}/{id}/{property}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data REST requires a version field annotated with `@Version` to achieve ETag, according to the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#conditional.etag).

If you want to version an embedded property (field), how can you version that single embedded property individually? The answer is impossible.

If you want to version a referenced property (JPA join), then you should make a PUT/PATCH/DELETE request to /{that-property-repository}/{id} instead of /{repository}/{id}/{property}.